# Books for Complex Methods in Sciences

Tags: resource-recommendations, complex-numbers

I am looking to study QM but I found out that I don't understand all the complex number representation like plane waves and many more. So what are some good books to study this topic of complex analysis used in plane wave representation etc in the beginner level? The book should be of a beginner level and I like it to be of simple maths not to complicated, something that a high schooler can understand.

Comment: This post and title (v2) seem too broad to be useful.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have edited my question if it still seems to broad kindly tell

Comment: Don't forget to edit the title accordingly.